# PHP write from Hidden Form Not Working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write to a file using data that was inputted through hidden form fields.  However, when the data gets written to the new file, it doesn't actually make it there.  The other stuff I wrote in with it is there, but the **data pulled in** does not show up.

If I "inspect element" in Firefox, the fields *are* filled properly.  Here is my code:

PHP Write Script (postthereview.php):

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$busname = $_POST['busname']; 
$review = $_POST['review'];
$data = nl2br('<b>Name:</b>' . '    ' . $firstname . "\n" . '<b>Business Name:</b>' . '    ' . $busname . "\n" . '<b>Review:</b>' . '   ' . $review . "\n" . '<hr>');

    $file = "../reviewsonpage.php"; 
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $ret = file_put_contents($file, $data . $contents); 
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="postthereview.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John">
   <input type="hidden" name="busname" value="Test Business">
   <input type="hidden" name="review" value="Hey!  Here is my review!">
   <input type="submit" value="Post it!">
</form>
```

I am new to this, and just cannot figure out why the data doesn't make it through!  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are both of these on the same PHP page?  That is, is the server-side code running when the page *loads* before the form is even posted?

Comment: David--  No, the form is in one file, and the PHP script is in another.

Comment: Basically, the form is just sitting on the webpage with the data already in the hidden fields.  Then, if someone clicks the Submit button, it will call the script to write the file.

Comment: Can you try to narrow down where the failure occurs?  In Firebug, does the POST request include the values?  Can the target page echo the values back to the output to prove they're there server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot **method="post"**
always put method Get or Post
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form

```
<form action="postthereview.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John">
   <input type="hidden" name="busname" value="Test Business">
   <input type="hidden" name="review" value="Hey!  Here is my review!">
   <input type="submit" value="Post it!">
</form>
```